# Send mail on mayor ruby on rails error exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a gem or way to send a mail with action mailer to a predefined admin@myhost.ltd ?
I have been looking for some gems to handle exceptions and notify me when a production app has serious issues turndowns or other major failures.

Would like to be notified by email in those cases,
Anyone can recommend me a good GEM to handle this ?

Comment: Do you mean "major" failures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this[1]

I never used, but can work for you

[1] https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification

Comment: Yes something like this , only I wonder if this is rails 3.2 compatible its 2 years old, have a look at it thx for posting

Comment: Sorry, i post the wrong repo, the new is up and running in https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification

Answer (score 2):

There are some notification tools like [Airbrake](http://airbrake.io/) that can help you with this, but the easy solution is to just add a `rescue_from` to your main controller to capture them.

Just be sure that your rescue method doesn't try and rescue its own exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

For those that do want to go commercial, one with really useful email notifications for exceptions (including daily error summary/aggregate email options) is [Raygun](http://raygun.io) - it has a ruby gem available at https://rubygems.org/gems/raygun4ruby.